# Solving the following trigonometric identities

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to solved the given identities but I cannot get the right answers

$\displaystyle\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{a}{2} - b\right) = \cos(b) - \sin(c)$

$\displaystyle\sin(a)\sin\left(\frac{a}{2}\right) = \cos(c + b)$

Where, $a = \pi/2 - c -b $. So far, for the first equation using the L.H.S and inputting the value of $a$ in it yields

$\displaystyle\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{c}{2} - \frac{b}{2}\right)$

from here on, using $\cos(A + B) = \cos(A)\cos(B) - \sin(A)\sin(B)$ I reach the following equation

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\cos\left(\frac{c}{2}\right) - \sin\left(\frac{c}{2}\right)\right)\left(\cos\left(\frac{b}{2}\right) - \sin\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)\right)$

From here on I cannot get to the required equation. The second one as well, after plugging in the value of $a$ breaks down to a similar equation.

Answer (score 0):

Friend you  are given a=π/2-(b+c)

So plug the value of.     b+c=π/2-a

So    sin(a)sin(a/2)=sin(a)

That makes   sin(a)=0.  or   sin(a/2)=1
And the rest work remains on your part!!